# Understanding STRUCTURED_POINTS dataset in VTK

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vtk

Based on my readings this is what I have gathered:

Dimensions: Number of data points in the x, y, z directions

Spacing: Space between points in each dimension

Origin: Location of origin

Cell data: Number of total points

I must have a misunderstanding somewhere, as the file I am working with has dimensions 13 13 13, yet my cell data is 1728. Would anyone be able to assist in pointing out my misunderstanding?

Also, following all the above declarations I see the VTK file outputs a lot of numbers. What do these numbers represent exactly?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the official documentation of the VTK file format?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Yes I have read through it but am still a little confused on certain parts, I tried looking for another resource or example but was unable to find anything.

Comment: Consider a 1-D line that's been divided into two cells.  You will get 3 nodes and nodal data of dimension 3, but the cell-centered data will be of dimension 2.

Comment: @BiswajitBanerjee Ahh I see that makes sense, thank you. Regarding the second question, take the answer to the following question as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323373/vtk-structured-point-file. How come despite the dimensions being 3x4x2, the values at the bottom are arrays of size 6?

Comment: The arrays are not of size 6, they're just printed that way.  Each line contains the index (i j k) and vector values (x y z).  

The best way I can think of for you is to try out the VTK functionality in Python (https://pypi.org/project/vtk/) to get an understanding of the data structures (and agorithms) and then moving to C++ when you need speed or integration with a C++ framework.